# Meaning of「悪いとは思うけれど」in this context

Tags: meaning, phrases

This is an excerpt from パン屋再襲撃 by 村上春樹. The main character and his wife are robbing a McDonald's. A girl who works there asks them a question.

> 「どうしてこんなことをしなくちゃいけないんですか？」と女の子が僕に向かって言った。「お金を持って逃げて、それで好きなものを買って食べればいいのに。だいいちビッグマックを三十個食べたって、それがいったい何の役に立つっていうの？」
>   僕は何も答えずにただ首を横に振った。
>   「**悪いとは思うけれど**、パン屋が開いてなかったのよ」と妻がその女の子に説明した。「パン屋が開いていれば、ちゃんとパン屋を襲ったんだけれど」

My question is what does 悪いとは思うけれど mean? Who's thinking, and what do they think is bad?

Comment: マクドナルドを襲ったのは悪いと思うけど、パン屋を襲うことは悪いと思わないのね。。。これって、コミカルな話？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

悪いとは思うけれど here means "I do feel sorry [for what we're doing to you], but"

The wife, who says this line, is expressing her apologetic feelings to the McDonald's girl. To paraphrase a little, she's essentially saying "Sorry you ended up being the one that we robbed, but the bakery wasn't open. So we chose this place instead."

悪い here is a word that expresses that one feels apologetic, like 申し訳ない or すまない. From [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/238878/meaning/m0u/%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84/):

> わる・い【悪い】
>   ➄ 謝罪・感謝の意を表す語。申し訳ない。すまない。
>   「心配をかけて、―・いね」
>   「―・いけれど先に帰るよ」
>   「―・い―・い。こんど埋め合わせします」